# fplot creates problems for empty matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

`fplot` creates problems for empty matrices, how to solve?
The matrices `solu1`, `solu2`, `solu3`, contain data, but the other matrices `solu4` and `solu5` do not contain data because these gaps `[]`, I need all these matrices to be present, how could I solve this?

```
syms x y real ;
eqn1=x.^3==y
eqn2=3-2.*x==y
eqn3=-2==x
solu1=double(vpa(struct2cell(solve([eqn1,eqn2],[x,y],'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))));
solu2=double(vpa(struct2cell(solve([eqn1,eqn3],[x,y],'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))));
solu3=double(vpa(struct2cell(solve([eqn2,eqn3],[x,y],'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))));
solu4=[];solu5=[];
matriz=double([solu1'; solu2'; solu3'; solu4'; solu5']);
matrizx=matriz(:,1);
matrizy=matriz(:,2);
datmax=([min(matrizx),max(matrizx)]);
e1=solve(eqn1,y);
e2=solve(eqn2,y);
plot(matrizx,matrizy,'or');
fplot(str2func(strcat('@(x)',char(e1))),datmax,'-r');
fplot(str2func(strcat('@(x)',char(e2))),datmax,'-b');
```

Comment: hes possible to reproduce the example i am giving you, i already modified it

Comment: solu4 and only5 are created inside an if because if a fourth equation were to be put, the data of these matrices should be created, but when the condition is not valid, empty values are assigned to them.

Comment: You could assign `nan(2,1)` to them instead of `[]`. `plot` will not plot any points with a NaN value. But what is the problem with `[]`? Your code seems to work OK. I just added a `hold on` after the first `plot`, so that all plots would show up at the same time. Also `str2func(strcat('@(x)',char(e1)))` is a weird construct and should not be used. Instead, do `matlabFunction(e1)`.

Comment: I was right, the error was solved, how do I rate you on this platform?

Comment: Thanks Cris Luengo